# How to make JavaFX WebView skip some specified sub-urls?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

How to make JavaFX WebView skip some specified sub-urls when loading a big web page? For example, making it not download images.

Comment: I would load it while the WebView isn’t showing (or possibly using a different WebView’s engine), then pass the [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty) through a [Transformer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) based on [XSL](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/) that removes the unwanted content.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I can't find the way to get the whole document before loading it. So do you know whether JavaFX WebView has provided such API?

Comment: By definition, you have to load the Document in order to have a Document.  However, I am not sure whether loading the Document will cause referenced images to be loaded, if the WebView is not in a visible Scene.

Comment: emmm... And it's hard to test and verify because of the uncertainty of network speed.

Comment: I did some tests, and it seems that the WebEngine gets the whole document before the WebView renders the page. So probably what you said before("load it while the WebView isn’t showing") is the solution.